# Docker-compose: build could not find Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
/path/
   web/
      Dockerfile
      docker-compose.yml
   file.zip
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tags:
      - "test/example1:latest"
```

Run docker compose:

```
> cd /path/web
> docker-compose up

failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1535462816/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

If building the image from command line directly, it works.

```
cd /path/web
docker build -f Dockerfile test/example1:latest ..
```

Comment: Check the context path. Change from `..` to  `.`

Comment: context is the parent path since Dockerfile COPY files from parent path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dockerfile: web/Dockerfile`

The [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#dockerfile) specifies an alternative file to build with. Since you use [context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#context) as `..`, the docker daemon will use `..` as the build context and the Dockerfile will use `/path/web` as it's root for file path references with the Dockerfile in `/path/web/Dockerfile` as the alternate Dockerfile.

Comment: But -f Dockerfile works on command-line. Any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't have worked. It's likely that a previously cached build is causing build steps to be skipped. To verify, delete the image, then try running the `docker build` again. [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) documentation states that the `<src>` path must be inside the context of the build so as long as the context is correct, referenced paths will be relative to the context.